# First query in Django is always slow

Tags: sql, django, mariadb

I have a simple Django app, just two models and a view. 
Whenever I query the db, the first query always takes about a second, and any query after that is almost instantaneous.

My view looks like this:

```
def my_view(request):
     start = time.time()
     print('0', time.time() - start)

     a = TestClass.objects.get(name="test")
     print('1', time.time() - start)

     b = TestCustomer.objects.get(name="test")
     print('2', time.time() - start)

     return render(request, 'test.html', {})
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
0 0.0
1 1.0049302577972412
2 1.0059285163879395
```

which means that the first query is much slower than the second one.

If I comment out the first query, (the `TestClass` query), I get the following output:

```
0 0.0
1 0.0
2 1.0183587074279785
```

meaning that the TestCustomer query suddenly got a lot slower. 
Both models have one field only (`name`, which is a CharField).

How come the first query is always so much slower? I have tried disabling Debug but that makes no difference. And if I run the queries directly, bypassing Django, they're instantaneous:

```
SELECT  `customers_testcustomer`.`id`, 
        `customers_testcustomer`.`name` 
 FROM   `customers_testcustomer` 
 WHERE  `customers_testcustomer`.`name` = 'test';

/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0,000 sec. */
```

Comment: The first query will open a connection, etc. So there is some extra overhead for the first query.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by using the CONN_MAX_AGE parameter for the DB, which keeps the connection alive, which is useful since I'm continuously fetching data

Comment: Something fishy going on; can you point me to the reference manual for `time.time()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the settings, the connection to the database might be closed after a request is finished. This is the case when [**`CONN_MAX_AGE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#conn-max-age) is set to `0`. As a result, for each request, a new connection has to be set up.

You can for example set `CONN_MAX_AGE` to `60`, such that you can reuse the connection that was opened by a previous request, and thus avoid this overhead. The very first query of your server might still be a bit slow, but the queries in the following requests will usually be faster.

Comment: This works perfectly, I'm updating the template every 5 seconds or so with a json request, so getting rid of that overhead really speeds things up.
Edit: Is there any downside to keeping the connection alive for a really long time?

Comment: @kycklingsylt: yes, it will result in some extra cycles to keep the connection alive. See the [*caveats*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#caveats).